# Adding custom components to a theme in mui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have two custom components, custom button and custom icon button, How can I add this to a theme in mui?

The following is my code

CustomButton.tsx

```
import { ReactNode } from "react";
import Button, { ButtonProps } from "@mui/material/Button";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
interface CustomButtonProps extends ButtonProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  // Add any additional props specific to your custom button
  // For example:
  // customProp: string;
}

const StyledButton = styled(Button)(({ theme }) => ({
  "&:hover": {
    backgroundColor: "blue",
  },
  "&:active": {
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
  "&.Mui-active": {
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
  },
}));

const CustomButton = ({ children, ...rest }: CustomButtonProps) => {
  return <StyledButton {...rest}>{children}</StyledButton>;
};

export default CustomButton;
```

CustomIconButton.tsx

```
 import { ReactNode } from "react";
    import IconButton, { IconButtonProps } from "@mui/material/IconButton";
    import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
    
interface CustomIconButtonProps extends IconButtonProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  // Add any additional props specific to your custom icon button
  // For example:
  // customProp: string;
}

const StyledIconButton = styled(IconButton)(({ theme }) => ({
  "&:hover": {
    backgroundColor: "blue",
  },
  "&:active": {
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
  "&.Mui-active": {
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
  },
}));

const CustomIconButton = ({ children, ...rest }: CustomIconButtonProps) => {
  return <StyledIconButton {...rest}>{children}</StyledIconButton>;
};

export default CustomIconButton;
```

App.tsx

```
import CustomButton from "./CustomButton";
import CustomIconButton from "./CustomIconButton";
import AccessAlarmsIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AccessAlarms";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <CustomButton variant="contained" color="primary">
        Custom Button
      </CustomButton>
      <CustomIconButton>
        <AccessAlarmsIcon />
      </CustomIconButton>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```